Why Castle.DynamicProxy could not create proxy class when origin class has a decimal paramter method
Old .net framework 4.8 project, use AutoFac.
I want to use AOP to instrument every method , but some class throw exception : System.Decimal is not a supported constant type.
There are a lot of methods have decimal request or response parameter, It's impossible to change decimal to other type.

There's clearly not enough here to even start helping. You may want to check out this article on asking a good question including the part on providing a minimal reproduction.
